# Why is the 'Object ID Key' node in Animation Nodes saying that my objects don't exist and don't have a location?

Tags: objects, animation-nodes

Got my hands on V1.7.5 of Animation Nodes and there is something I can't understand.

I create a group with 4 cubes and as I plug in an "Objects from Group" node to an "Object ID key" the Debug drawer show that those cubes don't exist and don't have any locations.

Yet I know this set up is supposed to work : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgozUx0KFBU

Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Please check the ID Keys panel in the AN tab of the toolbar in the 3d view. You have to save the Initial Transforms of the objects first before you can use them in the node tree.

Comment: That was it! Thanks man, keep up your work! You rock!